# Units kT = 1... why?

Tags: thermodynamics, units

Why is it convenient to choose units kT=1? It came up in this paper: http://jfi.uchicago.edu/~leop/SciencePapers/scaling%20and%20universality%20in%20statistical%20physics.pdf in page 4, equation (2.1).

Comment: Well, it's convenient since you don't have to write $kT$ as a prefactor anymore to anything, which would otherwise occur all the goddamn time. It really clutters equations if you leave it alone, the only thing worse is $\hbar$. ;)

Comment: It's like any chart that has numbers in thousands or millions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACuriousMind's comment in answer form: $kT$ is something that appears all the time in equations in thermodynamics. You can always choose suitable units to ensure that the quantity $kT = 1$ (think of it as some kind of normalisation if you like!).

To convert back to an answer that includes those $kT$'s we simply perform some dimensional analysis and insert the appropriate $kT$ quantities back.